# Appium: Unable to perform click on a "+" button

Tags: appium

I am trying to automate a mobile app, and I am having issues in trying to click a "+" to add new line of data.

From getsource(), the code for the element is

```
                <android.widget.ImageButton index="0" package="mobi.littlebytes.android.bloodglucosetracker" class="android.widget.ImageButton" text="" resource-id="mobi.littlebytes.android.bloodglucosetracker:id/fab" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[844,1558][1038,1752]" displayed="true" />
              </android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

and my failed code is

```
a.moveToElement(driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='fab']"))).click().build().perform();
```

I have also tried

```
a.moveToElement(driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mobi.littlebytes.android.bloodglucosetracker:id/fab']"))).click().build().perform();
```

but failed as well, that is, couldn't get to click the "+" button. Hope to have advice.

I attached the image of the button

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clicking the element by using the xpath:

```
driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='mobi.littlebytes.android.bloodglucosetracker:id/fab']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks @Sameer ! Could you teach me what is the difference with your code with the solution that uses the "contain" method ?

Comment: @Tester_at_work I haven't used `moveToElement` method as the element is already present on the page and `contains` would give all the element which contains that text, so it is advisable to enter the exact text